# How can I change a torrent's name?

Tags: download, bittorrent, utorrent, p2p

How can I change a torrent's display name which appears in the torrent client before or after I start any download?

Comment: Openly sharing screenshots depicting illegal downloading of copyrighted materials using your real name may not be the wisest decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark the torrent you want to rename and press `[F2]`.

Answer (score 1):

With [qbittorrent](http://www.qbittorrent.org) it's a simple right click -> rename.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [BEncode Editor](https://sites.google.com/site/ultimasites/bencode-editor) to edit the torrent file before adding to your Bittorrent Client.

You have to change "name" attribut under "info":

[image]

Comment: After changing the file name under the "name" attribute in BEncode; seems like the torrent file is damaged as the download does not start. Am I missing something here? (Damaged hashcodes etc.)

Comment: I did just test it and it worked. Perhaps there are no peers available.

Comment: No, you can't edit the name directly in the `.torrent`-file. That will change the´`hash` of the torrent and make it impossible to find the other peers in the swarm.